# Tomcat service memory exceeds max without failure

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, heap-memory

I've read a multitude of posts but clearly I'm missing something in my understanding.  I have a Tomcat service, which is installed with:

```
--JvmMx=1000
--JvmMs=128
```

I've verified that these settings are successful via calls such as:

```
PsExec.exe -s {jdk}\bin\jinfo.exe -flag MaxHeapSize {pid}
```

However, the tomcat7.exe process for this service consistently grows, exceeding this maximum by factors of 3 or more until it brings the server to a crawl.  Weirdly, this is only an issue on one server; everywhere else it's fairly constant and remains under the limit. I've also looked for memory leaks in my development environment and have found none.

To debug this, I've tried forcing the GC like so:

```
 PsExec.exe -s {jdk}\bin\jcmd.exe {pid} GC.run
```

But this seems to have no effect. So next I set it up for jconsole monitoring by adding this to the installation:

```
tomcat7.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"
tomcat7.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8086"
tomcat7.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
tomcat7.exe //US//%SERVICE_NAME% ++JvmOptions="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

Now (of course!) it's well-behaved.  GC is clearly working and the process memory is staying below the limit.

I'm baffled.  Max heap is 1 GB, permanent memory is 90 MB, stack size is defaulted, so about 128KB? And the thread count, which does not grow, is "only" 67.  So how can the process memory rise to 3+ GB? And why isn't it throwing an out of memory exception?

Even now, the "well-behaved" service according to jconsole is only using about 50 MB of heap, running on 57 threads.  Yet Task Manager is showing 71 threads using 800 MB. I assume the difference is due to Tomcat, is it? Please help me fill in the gaps of my understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Java uses more memory than just what you need for the Java heap spaces. It's called "native memory" and isn't counted in any of the memory spaces you've been mentioning / checking.

This post will open your eyes:
http://www.evanjones.ca/java-native-leak-bug.html

(FWIW, setting `-Xms` and `-Xmx` to different values for a server process is simply a waste of time. Set them to the same value so that the heap doesn't need to be re-sized a bunch of times on the way "up" to the max heap size. If you are going to provision e.g. 1GiB to the server process, you may as well allow it to be used right away.)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That's interesting! Though I don't know if it applies here. The service has mostly been unused, and so it just loops through checking the DB for work to perform and logging a status. Certainly not much concurrency. I suppose the DB calls are probably native. It just seems odd that JVM code would grow so large.  Is there a way to limit that growth?

Comment: @Didjit There is no way I know of to limit the size of the native memory used by the JVM, short of limiting process memory at the OS level -- which will of course terminate the process if it exceeds that limit. It won't actually get the JVM to stay under such a limit.

Answer (score 0):

from official documentation I found :

> --JvmMs       Initial memory pool size in MB. (Not used in exe mode.)
>
> --JvmMx       Maximum memory pool size in MB. (Not used in exe mode.)

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/windows-service-howto.html

try to add `--StartMode jvm  --Jvm` if you don't already