# Tomcat Service Memory Keeps Growing, but JVM Memory is stable

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, memory-leaks, jvm

I've asked for help on this before, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45866930/tomcat-service-memory-exceeds-max-without-failure), but the issue still exists and the previously accepted answer doesn't explain it. I've also read most every article and SO thread on this topic, and most point to application leaks or modest overhead, neither of which I believe explain what I'm seeing.

I have a fairly large web service (application alone is 600MB), which when left alone grows to 5GB or more as reported by the OS. The JVM, however, is limited to 1GB (Xms, Xmx).

I'd done extensive memory testing and have found no leaks whatsoever. I've also run Oracle's Java Mission Control (basically the JMX Console) and verified that actual JVM use is only about 1GB. So that means about 4GB are being consumed by Tomcat itself, native memory, or the like.

I don't think and JNI, etc. is to blame as this particular installation has been mostly unused. All it's been doing is periodically checking the database for work requests, and periodically monitoring its resource consumption. Also, this hasn't been a problem until recently after years of use.

The JMX Console does report a high level of fragmentation (70%). But can that alone explain the additional memory consumption?

Most importantly, though, is not so much *why* is this happening, but *how* can I fix/configure it so that it stops happening. Any suggestions?

Here are some of the details of the environment:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit
- Java 1.7.0.25
- Tomcat 7.0.55
- JvmMX, JvmMs = 1000  (1GB)
- Thread count: 60
- Perm Gen: 90MB

Also seen on:

- Windows 2012 R2 64-bit
- Java 1.8.0.121

[image: Service Process]

[image: JVM Memory Use Profile]

[image: JMX Console Overview]

Comment: Now that you added graphs, I see nothing about **native** memory there, and your problem is with native memory, not JVM heap memory. The linked article in the answer *you* linked to is all about native memory, so why are you still focused on heap memory???

Comment: @Andreas, the focus on heap was to show that the heap isn't the problem, in anticipation of responses about setting heap size and debugging memory leaks. Next, when I say the previous answer doesn't explain it, it's because the article is about a leak in gzip, which isn't actively used by the application in its quiescent state, which is the current situation. I agree about the native or meta memory being the issue, and perhaps a JNI malloc is the ultimate cause, so I am pursuing that. But it's not a simple task.

Comment: [cont'd] So while I work on that front I was hoping for insight on the effects of fragmentation, or using Native Memory Tracking, or MaxMetaspaceSize, which I just discovered.